# Как синхронизировать ветку Git между компьютерами? git push выдает "ветка Х не имеет вышестоящей ветки"

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push, git-branch

У меня есть ветка master и ветка develop. Находясь в ветке develop я хочу создать новую ветку фитч, к примеру, my_fitch, находясь на работе я разрабатываю функционал и делаю коммиты, после прихожу домой и хочу продолжить разработку. Как мне это реализовать ?

Если я пытаюсь выполнить git push то выдает ошибку:

```
fatal: Текущая ветка myfeature не имеет вышестоящей ветки.
Чтобы отправить текущую ветку и установить внешнюю ветку как вышестоящую для этой ветки,
```

Но мне не нужно пока что мержить с веткой develop, так как я еще не закончил разработку в ветке my_fitch.

Comment: Пушить в удаленный репо ветку my_fitch. `git push origin my_fitch`

Comment: Подскажите как ?

Comment: `git push origin -u my_fitch`

Comment: Причём тут хорёк интересно 

Comment: @dIm0n fitch - дитя fetch и feature